# Como restringir o acesso externo a instância do Redis instalado em uma imagem docker

Tags: redis, docker, telnet

Olá, estou recebendo e-mail, sobre meu servidor que tem uma imagem docker do redis instalado e usa a porta 6379, falando que está aberto a conexões externas.

Redis listens for traffic from everywhere on port 6379, and you can validate this report by attempting to connect to your Redis on 6379 via a simple telnet command:

```
    telnet 111.111.111.111 6379
```

Essa é uma parte do e-mail, (eu mascarei o IP para colocar a mensagem aqui no fórum)
Eu também fiz o teste para ver se a porta realmente está aberta a conexões externas no site, https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/
, e realmente apresenta que a porta 6379 do ip do meu servidor está aberta.
E o email diz para fazer o seguinte
Remediation of this issue will take just a few minutes and is relatively straightforward. You will need to open /etc/redis/redis.conf and uncomment (remove the “#”) or modify the line beginning with:

```
    #bind 127.0.0.1 ::1
```

Afterwards, restart redis with:

```
    sudo systemctl restart redis
```

Gostaria de saber se alguém pode me ajudar, visto que não consigo acessar o arquivo redis.config dentro do servidor, pois o redis está em uma imagem do docker, ou pelo menos não sei como acessar. Existe alguma maneira de bloquear o acesso externo ao meu redis instalado por uma imagem docker?

Comment: Qual comando utiliza para executar a imagem docker?

Comment: O comando utilizado foi esse, docker run --name redis -p 6379:6379 -d -t redis:alpine

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Uma alternativa à editar o `redis.config` é fazer o bind do docker apenas ao ***localhost***. Que segundo a documentação pode ser alcançado da seguinte forma:

```
docker run --name redis -p 127.0.0.1:6379:6379 -d -t redis:alpine
```

Saiba mais na [documentação](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/)

Repare que para executar este comando acima você deve parar a execução do container atual (que está fazendo o bind no host [0.0.0.0]) e iniciar o container o redis novamente.

Só isso deve solucionar.

Em uma configuração que eu fiz para verificar o funcionando é possível ver que o bind foi feito apenas ao localhost. Fiz essa verificação utilizando apenas o comando `docker ps`.

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                       COMMAND                  PORTS                                       NAMES
122d38e6728a   redis:alpine                "docker-entrypoint.s…"   127.0.0.1:6379->6379/tcp                    redis
cf64f2a1e0bb   nodered/node-red:2.2.2-12   "npm --no-update-not…"   0.0.0.0:1880->1880/tcp, :::1880->1880/tcp   iot-man-node-red
```

Em uma eu criei utilizando o comando acima disponibilizado e em outra eu apenas fiz o bind das portas, sem setar o localhost.

---

### Desejo realmente modificar o redis.config

Devido à sua simplicidade é possível iniciar um redis sem nenhum arquivo de configuração. Que é o caso para a imagem docker do redis (pelo menos a imagem oficial disponibilizada pelo redis).

Na [documentação](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis), é possível iniciar um redis via um arquivo de configuração. Neste caso você vai ter que ter um modelo, segue o que a documentação sugere:

```
FROM redis
COPY redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
CMD [ "redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf" ]
```

Neste caso você está copiando um arquivo `redis.conf` para dentro da imagem, e depois está iniciando um redis-server apontando para o arquivo de configuração que foi copiado para a imagem.

Comment: Para não perder tempo, eu removi a imagem do redis, e iniciei uma nova com o comando, docker run --name redis -p 127.0.0.1:6379:6379 -d -t redis:alpine, que você passou, e deu certo a porta 6379, agora está fechada para acesso externo, vou considerar aprender sobre o firewall e poder implementar também, e muito obrigado pela ajuda!!